# Variable won't set

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, variable-assignment

I have an object similar to this in node:

```
unique_obj={
    unique:true,
    change:function(){
        this.unique=false;
        console.log(this.unique);
    }
}
unique_obj.change();
```

but console still logs true. I don't have any async functions in my code except one that reads data from a file that calls my main function that reads everything else. I've stepped through the code in VS 2015, and it seems like the variable doesn't get modified. What could be the culprit? I can't figure it out. There is only one variable named unique and one instance of the unique_obj in the whole script (there's no reference to any other scripts).

Comment: It can not be `true` ! I tried in my console , logs `false` ;

Comment: It must be `false` always in your console.

Comment: Can you check it on node shell?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `unique` is not a "variable", it's a "property". Anyway, there is something here you are not showing us.

Comment: Yes this script logs false. Which leaves me wondering what could cause it to log true? Is there anything around it that could possibly cause it to log true? I haven't tried running my script in node, but I would guess it's either human error. I'm just looking for some possible leads. I'll run my script in node and see what happens.

Comment: So it works properly in vanilla node. I tried turning off all my breakpoints and I get the expected behavior. The weirder thing is if I step through, it logs true and the variable doesn't get changed, but if I continue, I get the expected behavior. I would still like some possible leads as for what could cause this behavior. It would be difficult to continue developing this without breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty watchlist! I was pretty sure my watchlist was clean, but one of the getters that checks some conditionals and also sets some properties according to the result, which then made breaking the program buggy.